# Error running Weblogic12.2.1.2.0: Weblogic installation registry file is not found

Tags: java, intellij-idea, weblogic

recently I have deinstalled my weblogic 12.1.1.0 from drive C, based on instruction of uninstallaiton, and I installed new version of weblogic "Quick Installer for Mac OSX, Windows and Linux" 12.2.1.2.0 in drive C but different folder. when I want to run weblogic in intellije I recieve the following error in intellij:
Error running Weblogic12.2.1.2.0: Weblogic installation registry file is not found
what is the problem?

Comment: can you post the whole stacktrace

Comment: See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-160465#comment=27-1597566

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem.

[image]

This problem occurs because the IntelliJ IDEA is getting the path (WEBLOGIC_HOME) for your wrong destination (your old installation).

So, to solve this you need to set a new path installation for your Weblogic settings in the IDE.

To do this, go tho your **Run** settings and click the **Configure** button on your Application Server settings, and then in your Weblogic Home set your new path, as the following image:

[image]

After this, you will run your Weblogic properly!

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue because I deleted my weblogic and reinstalled it at a different location. All I did to fix it was change the location of my weblogic home within IntelliJ to match the new location.